# File encryption with AES-256-CBC vs Chunk encryption

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm basically designing a protocol that requires a **synchronous and ordered** file transmission from a server (implemented in Node.js) to a device, over **TCP**. Streaming the file is not an option, so each file chunk is encapsulated in a message that has other non-encrypted fields, which are out of scope of this question.

One of the requirements is that the file contents can not be sent in plain text, so an encryption scheme had to be chosen, in this case I opted for the **AES-256-CBC**, assume for the purpose of this question that the algorithm can't be changed.

Due to device constraints (RAM ~10KB), it's required to split the file (**<5 MB**) into chunks, that will be then sent to the device according to the mentioned protocol, following a **send / [ack|repeat]** scheme. On reception, the device is able to store the chunk on disk.

So my main question here is that in the backend I have to choose between:

- **Encrypting the complete file and then split it into chunks**

  -> On reception device would append each chunk in a file and then decrypt it when all chunks were received.

### **vs**

- **Dividing the file into chunks and then encrypt each of them.**

  -> Requires the sending of the **Initialization Vector** (IV) used on each chunk encryption in order to decrypt it.

  -> On chunk reception the device would have to decrypt the chunk or store each of them with the respective IV and then decrypt them after receiving the last chunk.

**The goal here is to understand what security issues arise from each approach and also an overhead comparison between them.**

PS: I also have an integrity validation scheme but is out of the question's ambit.

Comment: @SerDom: are you aware that you could encrypt, transmit and decrypt the data on the fly (CBC block by block), i.e. there is no need to encrypt the whole file first or split the file into chunks with separate encryption. And if you would use AES-GCM instead of AES-CBC this would also include integrity validation already.

Comment: Imagin for instance that the connection with device is lost, would it be posible, with the GCM aproach, on re-connection to continue the process from the previous state (before disconnection) @SteffenUllrich

Comment: It does not matter if the underlying connection breaks or not since the encryption does not need to be bound to a specific connection (it just needs to keep some internal state). You only need to guarantee that the data arrive complete, in the correct order and without duplicates on the other side which you need to guarantee anyway. It does not matter how many connections you need to transfer the data to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your train of thought. The question here is that I need to send the file contents encrypted to the device and I cannot send them in a single write operation. So if by any reason the connection is lost in the middle of the transfer I want to leave space to implement a recover scheme functionality where the server will keep the transfer from the disconnection state. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: It's kind of like this: 1. initialize AES engine at server and client side with the same key. 2. Feed one block into the AES engine at the server to encrypt it and send the result to the client. If the client fails to receive it send it again (maybe creating a new connection if needed) and again until the client got it. 3. At the client side feed the received block into the AES engine to decrypt it. 4. repeat with #2 until no more input data.

Comment: I'm developing the backend in Node.js, using the ["Crypto" native module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), thus I'm not able to feed block by block, It's a lot more abstracted than that, a GCM encryption aprroach would sound like this [example](https://gist.github.com/chris-rock/fe87dd35d6168512a2f7) and as you can check the block feeding is abstracted. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: I would also like to return the focus to the main question of the split encrypted file vs encrypt file chunks assuming that the only available option is the AES-CBC algorithm

Comment: @SerDom That Crypto module looks like it'd work to call `update` where data has the length of 1 block.

Comment: It's not posible, since the getAuthTag method can only be called at the end of the encryption process, after cipher.final() @AndrolGenhald

Comment: @SerDom Why does that matter? You'd just send it after you finish sending the ciphertext.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald there in no point on calling `update` since in order to send the ciphered text, in GCM, the authTag is needed and it's only available after calling `final`. So if you wanted to cipher block by block 1) you will have to call the`final` method 2) then get the `authTag` 3) send it to the device. 4) Repeat 1 till all blocks of data are sent

Comment: @SerDom Maybe the example you linked is confusing you, the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_setauthtag_buffer) only states that `setAuthTag` must be called before `final`. It's fine (or at least it should be, I haven't tested it) to call `update` any number of times before setting the tag. Also note that that example fails to verify the tag length, which is _required_!

Comment: @AndrolGenhald [please read the last sentence of this section](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_getauthtag) "The cipher.getAuthTag() method should only be called after encryption has been completed using the cipher.final() method."

Comment: @SerDom Yes, `getAuthTag` is called on the encrypting end after encryption has finished, then the end decrypting calls `setAuthTag` _just before_ finishing the decryption.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald exactly, but the point discussed by Steffen is about the encryption process (yeah, decryption will follow the same scheme), stating that it would encrypt block by block, which would have to be done like in the example mentioned before, getting each ciphered block with the following flow: 1-`update() final() getAuthTag() send()`. I'm afraid that you are confusing the process described in the question.

Comment: @SerDom I don't follow. What's stopping you from doing `while (more data) {update(); send();} final(); send(); getAuthTag(); send();`, and on the receiving end `while (more data) {receive(); update();} receive(); setAuthTag(); final();`?

Comment: @AndrolGenhald because the encrypted data is only one of the many fields sent on the "packet" to the device. The encrypted data has to be sent with the authTag (following GCM) in order to allow the device to decrypt the `crypted field` on each packet reception. The authTag can only be retrieved after calling `final()`. Your implementation would work in an approach where the device only decrypts after receiving all file's data. So basically you are going deeper on the implementation details, but opting for the second choice, where one splits the file in "chunks" and encrypts them, is that it?

Answer (score 3):

Security wise, I don't see there is any difference.

Since integrity and availability are assumed to be handled properly, the only concern is confidentiality. Solution 1 uses only one IV, assuming you can generate good IVs (random and long enough), then that is fine. Solution 2 uses multiple IVs but they don't add more to security (IVs are all public). Indeed IVs are used to randomize ciphertext so that the chosen plaintext attack is not possible. One IV for the whole file is sufficient for this purpose. In solution 1 all data is encrypted under one key. This is the same in solution 2. Then confidentiality boils down to the security of this key. There is no difference in both solutions.

There might be some difference when it comes to performance. Solution 2 allows encryption and decryption to be done in parallel. This is not the case in solution 1. On the other hand, solution 2 requires slightly more space/computation/bandwidth due to the additional IVs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as It goes straight to the main point discussed.

Comment: Are there any references available discussing solution 2?